# Slowing a batch file down to read errors

Tags: batch-file

With batch, if you get an error, the most you see of it is a flash of text and then the program ends. Is there anyway to have it slow down? or to have it stop before closing when it hits an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

If you execute your Batch file from the command-line in a MS-DOS window and an error happens, you can just review the text in the window to see what happened.

On the other hand, if you execute the Batch file via a double click in the explorer you see nothing if the Batch file have an error. Is this your case? If so, the easiest solution is to test the Batch file in a MS-DOS window until it works ok.

However, if you still need a method to stop closing the DOS window when the Batch file ends, you can do that this way:

- Right click on your Batch file and select Create shorcut, a Shorcut is created.
- Right click on the Shortcut and select Properties
- In Target, after the "C:\Path\filename.bat" string add: & PAUSE
- Select OK

This way, when you execute the Shortcut via a double click, the DOS window will execute a PAUSE after the Batch file ends for any reason.

Comment: Thats a good point. By running it via the MS-DOS window then will be like Calling the Bat file. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethJones: Excuse me. If you think my answer is useful, may I ask for your upvote? Thanks! BTW, did you see my answer in your "5 seconds timer in set /p" question? I think my answer may enrich a lot your Batch game!

Comment: I tried to, but cause the wireless down my end of the house sucks so much, it bounced back with an error. Also i did see your answer, thanks, it was a great help, as i didn't know about external programs like that were available for batch

Comment: This was very useful, batch file worked when ran from the command prompt but not when clicked (due to relative path)

Comment: This is not a fully useful answer. Some batch scripts launch another cmd.exe, which means that none of this is relevant.

Comment: I was looking for the best answer to see error when lauching a bat file, and I think this answer is not the best way to do it, it's too complex! Look at this solution (executing a bat from cmd.exe): [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118846/how-to-prevent-batch-window-from-closing-when-error-occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118846/how-to-prevent-batch-window-from-closing-when-error-occurs)

Answer (score 4):

Redirect the output with > to capture it in a file.

You might need:  *command* > *file* 2>&1

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: For the benefit of others who find this post: The second suggestion will include error messages in the output file on Windows 7 (and I assume older). If you leave off the 2>&1 part, errors go to the console, which can also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] (
    pause
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Comment: This works! I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Run the script from a present CMD.exe and add "exit /b 1" to the scripts end of file. Remove any simple "exit".

Comment: `exit /b 1` means "exit this batch script _with error code 1_". It does not mean "exit this batch script only if an error code has been set", which is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Open a new cmd window and execute your command there. The newly opened window will not be closed when an error occurs.

```
start cmd /k [command]
```

This works for me with basic commands. Not sure if it's useful for anything more advanced.

Comment: you can also pipe commands like this: `start cmd /k "command 1 & command 2 & command 3"`

Answer (score 2):

To stop a batch script before it ends, put the `pause` command on a new line, which will make the script wait for user input (like an enter key) before continuing (or closing).

Comment: That wont work because if the batch file hits an error, it will crash, and so wont hit the end of the script, nor any pauses.

Answer (score 0):

for a second

```
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
```

or for 10secs

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Similar to @Sri7's answer but you need the brackets and quotes:

```
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
   pause
)
```