# How to prevent batch window from closing when error occurs?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write batch script to **create a folder if it does not already exist**.
Following up the online examples, below is my script.

The problem is; first `pause` works, then probably due to syntax error **the window closes** even before reaches to the second `pause`, so I can't really tell which part of my script is wrong.

Could anyone show me how to prevent closing window so that I can see what's on the window?

```
@echo off

:copy theme images over
:designer
echo copying theme images over...
pause
if not exist "%K2DIR%\K2 SmartForms Runtime\Styles\Themes\Sharepoint 2013\rich_text"
(
    md "%K2DIR%\K2 SmartForms Runtime\Styles\Themes\Sharepoint 2013\rich_text333"
)

pause
```

Comment: Why don't you put a `pause` before `md`? Also, don't just run the .bat file by doubleclicking it: open `cmd` and call your bat from there. No window to close there!

Comment: As for the syntax error - your `(` is misplaced. It must be on the same line as your IF statement with a space before it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to pass the /K switch to CMD, or just open a Command Window and run the batch from the command line.

Comment: `cmd /k myfile.bat`

Comment: in my case i needed this for debugging a nuitka build and this gave me a hint
`.\app.exe`

Comment: I tried using this as follows: `cmd /k env\Scripts\activate && python fedex_main.py --mode "draft" && pause` - however that does not seem to work. I can get it working by creating a new *.bat file, e.g. `python_env_file.bat` with the `env\Scripts\activate && python fedex_main.py --mode "draft" && pause` portion, then in a separate call `cmd /k python_env_file.bat` - but that seems overly convoluted vs. having everything in 1 file?

Answer (score 81):

You could put this line at the beginning of the batch file:

```
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )
```

What this line does is, the first time you run it, it re-launches itself in a subprocess that doesn't exit after it finishes running the batch file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Windows 7. It spawns recursive subprocesses until something fails. Anyone have any corrections?

Comment: @porcoesphino Can you try `if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )`

Comment: Oh wow. The space before the bracket was the issue. Does that also work in earlier versions? If so, it's probably worth updating your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @porcoesphino cmd never ceases to surprise me. Actually, I should say cmd keeps revealing new quirks all the time so it never surprises me any more. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: 'defined' is not recognized as an internal or external command? I don't know what's wrong on win7

Comment: @SLdraogn `defined` is a keyword that is recognised only by the `if` command. You can only use it in the context `if defined` or `if not defined`. Are you trying to use it on its own?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks for your information, I use bat to exe software compiles the bat file to exe, which show this error on win7 but win10 works fine, maybe there is a bug related to the software. I will investigate it, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Press `start` and type `cmd` and press `enter`, you will launch a command prompt.

**Just drag and drop what you need to run** (your python script, .exe ...) **into the cmd windows, and press enter.**

(You might some time to run the cmd as admin: find the cmd in the start menu, right-click on it, choose `run as admin`).

Comment: This was so easy. No need to modify my script, and it shows the last lines it failed on. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: TIL: Drag and drop to the CMD window is a thing. Nice timesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recorded the screen (bandicam) for when I couldn't quite read the error message, and then I could replay it; I suppose this is mainly helpful if you already have software on your computer.

Comment: this worked out great for me! It was a fleeting message and I did not have control over script invocation - this was the best option.

Answer (score 1):

using pause at  end  of  batch paused the cmd screen, tanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How to prevent batch window from closing when error occurs?

I had the problem when using robocopy. My solution was:

```
if not %errorlevel% lss 8 pause
```

For Robocopy every exit code below 8 is a success:
https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html